# Cannot align images in tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to set image to the right side. But I am unable to do so.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="hidden lg:block lg:bg-red-400 flex">
  <img class="h-10 justify-center" src="..." alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try "justify-end" instead of justify-center?

Comment: @TheGodfather Yes, did that too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

- Apply `justify-content: flex-end` via the `justify-end` class on the flex parent.
- Apply `margin-left: auto` via the `ml-auto` class on the `<img>` element.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-red-400 flex justify-end">
  <img class="h-10 justify-center" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" alt="">
</div>

<div class="bg-red-400 flex">
  <img class="h-10 justify-center ml-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" alt="">
</div>
```